# Is there any phrase or word to relate time, location and event?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I'm working on a research paper, I need a word or phrase which is related to users' location, time and event. If there's isn't exact word or phrase then any best fit would also work out.

Comment: What's a *users' event*?

Comment: [**Five Ws**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Ws) (link to Wikipedia); *Who*, *what*, *where*, *when* and *why* sometimes combined with *how*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [context](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Context)  may be used  to suggest what you are referring to:

> - the set of circumstances or facts that surround a particular event, situation, etc.
> - the conditions and circumstances that are relevant to an event, fact, etc

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest ***situation*** for this.

From The Free Dictionary's [collected definitions for *situation*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/situation), we find the following shades of meaning:

> state of affairs; combination of circumstances
>
> manner of being situated; location or position with reference to environment.
>
> the combination of circumstances at a given time

It is easy to infer from this that *situation* goes beyond mere physical placement to include other conceptual notions of placement. Certainly time and extended environment are amply covered.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest *anachronous* or *synchronous*.